# Pandas groupby apply complex to a different column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here I have a df:

```
    value   indicator
0   AABB    55
1   ABBCC   55
2   ACSCC   15
3   ACCBB   15
4   ACSSS   15
```

I wish to groupby by indicator, and calculate how big the difference is between strings. Method is to count how many letters exist in other rows.

For example, for `indicator=55`, `ABB` 3 letters coexist, for row0 it's 3/4, and for row1 it's 3/5. I need to groupby by indicator, take value `max(3/4, 3/5)`

Similar to `indicator=15`, but this time, we need to compare 3 times, row2 to row3, row2 to row4, and row3 to row4.

row2 to row3: ACC coexist, therefore 3/5 for both row

row2 to row4: ACS coexist, therefore 3/5 for both row

row3 to row4: AC coexist, therefore 2/5 for both row

Then we need to get `max(3/5, 3/5, 2/5)`.

This is too complicated to me, sometimes, indicator gets more than 3 same values, so permutation can be a little hassle.

Thanks all who'd like to solve this for me

So final table should be something look this this:

```
   value  indicator
0  0.75    55
3  0.6     15
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the string intersection (coexist) only matters between two strings? Not all strings of the same indicator? And then the proportion of shared characters of the string with the highest proportion of shared characters is returned for each indicator?

Comment: @DavidW take the example above, indicator=15, the intersection matters for 3 strings. and yes to the last question, highest proportion.

Comment: @DavidW ive learn fuzzywuzzy can do good job, only matter now is how to do permutation among indicator=15

Comment: Correct but just confirming that the joint intersection of the three strings is irrelevant.